# Add quotation at the start and end of each line in R

Tags: r, string, text

I am sorry that my question was unclear, so changed the question, a little bit.

I am pre-processing data of patent information with R. A part of the data includes applicants or companies name as follows:

```
head(patent$applicant)
[1] Flextronics AP, LLC                 Flextronics AP, LLC                 Flextronics AP, LLC                
[4] General Electric Company
```

How to insert double-quotes at the start and end of each line in R? The result I intend would be as follows:

```
head(patent$applicant)
[1] "Flextronics AP, LLC"                 "Flextronics AP, LLC"                 "Flextronics AP, LLC"                
[4] "General Electric Company"
```

Hope dput() help you understand my quesstio

```
head(dput(patent$applicant))
.......
"Zonar Systems, Inc.", "ZONAR SYSTEMS, INC.", "Zoom Information Systems", 
"Zoop Mobility Network Inc.", "Zynga Inc."), class = "factor")
[1] Flextronics AP, LLC                 Flextronics AP, LLC                        Flextronics AP, LLC                
[4] General Electric Company            GM Global Technology Operations LLC     Digimarc Corporation               
2994 Levels:  @Road, Inc. 1st Communications Inc. 2089275 ONTARIO LTD. ...    Zynga Inc.
```

And str(), as well.

```
str(patent$applicant)
Factor w/ 2994 levels "","@Road, Inc.",..: 864 864 864 956 1007 667 1512 2510 1671 1671 ...
```

I tried paste0(). The result is as follow:

```
head(paste0('"', patent$applicant, '"'))
[1] "\"Flextronics AP, LLC\""                 "\"Flextronics AP, LLC\""                
[3] "\"Flextronics AP, LLC\""                 "\"General Electric Company\""           
[5] "\"GM Global Technology Operations LLC\"" "\"Digimarc Corporation\""
```

Thank you for comments. It really helped me. 
I did it with single quotes, instead of double quotes.

```
> head(paste0("\'",patent$applicant,"\'"))
[1] "'Flextronics AP, LLC'"                 "'Flextronics AP, LLC'"                
[3] "'Flextronics AP, LLC'"                 "'General Electric Company'"           
[5] "'GM Global Technology Operations LLC'" "'Digimarc Corporation'"
```

Comment: What is this "list" of yours - a text file?

Comment: @Stedy - R will not automatically add quotes, it will `print()` with quotes to the screen in certain circumstances, but the base data is not changed.

Comment: Sorry, I re-wrote the question.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data.  It will help us in understanding the structure.

Comment: `as.character(patent$applicant)` - is that all you want? Which I might add, does **not** add quotation marks. `cat(patent$applicant)` will show you what the underlying text looks like.

Comment: `paste0('"', patent$applicant, '"')` if you actually want quotes as part of the strings.

Comment: You have a `factor`, which is a representation of categorical data like `group1`, `group2` etc. This is numeric data which has text labels attached. Use the `as.character` code above if you want this to be strictly character data.

Comment: @Gregor that's what I actually want. But, still has a small problem. Please, see above revised question.

Comment: Your paste result has `"`s included - see `cat("\"Flextronics AP, LLC\"","\n")` which gives `"Flextronics AP, LLC"`.

Comment: Thank you for all comments.

Comment: @Gnar Did the answer you accepted really help you?

Comment: @Pascal comments actually helped me. Why? lol

Comment: @Gnar I spoke about the answer, not the comments. Out of curiosity.

Comment: @Pascal I also thank the one that wrote the answer lol. Comments helped me more, though.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If the data is in String format , You can Use `paste()` function to have a leading and a trailing double quote.

Comment: While the questioner finds this answer usefull and marked as the desired answer why people downvoting it ? i am new so if there is something i don't know please let me know people .

Comment: Because at is, it is quite poor solution and give less useful information than the comments above (even the OP agreed with). You could add more value to this answer providing an example of how to use the solution you propose. Thus I will reconsider my downvote.